django-filter DateFromToRangeFilter can't not filte between two dates
I'm building vue3 + django DRF project. I'm making my consumelists from and I want to filte bewteen two days. likes 2024-06-01 to 2024-06-30.
I used DateFromToRangeFilter but not work. please help. omz
My model.py
class ConsumeDetails(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    consumetype = models.ForeignKey(ConsumeType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    consumepurpose = models.ForeignKey(ConsumePurpose, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        app_label = 'myweb'
        db_table = 'Consume_Details'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date

My filter.py
class ConsumeDetailsFilter(FilterSet):
    # date = filters.DateFilter(field_name='date')
    RegDate= DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='gte',lable='date range')
    category = filters.CharFilter(field_name='category', lookup_expr='icontains')
    subcategory = filters.CharFilter(field_name='subcategory', lookup_expr='icontains')
    vendor = filters.CharFilter(field_name='vendor', lookup_expr='icontains')
    item = filters.CharFilter(field_name='item', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = ConsumeDetails
        fields = ['RegDate','category', 'subcategory', 'vendor', 'item', 'price', 'remarks']

My serializers.py
class ConsumeDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    consumepurpose = ConsumePurposeSerializer()
    consumetype = ConsumeTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ConsumeDetails
        fields = '__all__'

My views.py
class ConsumeDetailsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ConsumeDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ConsumeDetailsSerializer

    filterset_fields = ['consumepurpose','consumetype','category','subcategory','RegDate']
    search_fields = ['category','subcategory','vendor','item']

    pagination_class = MyPageNumberPagination

Error message in here
enter image description here
I want use star_date and end_date to filte the range like the link below
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/consumedetails/?**start_date=2024-06-01&end_date=2024-06-30**

The error you are encountering is due to the RegDate field being included in the fields list within the Meta class. In a FilterSet, you should only add fields to the fields list if you want them to be autogenerated based on the model fields. Since you have defined a custom filter for RegDate above, there is no need to include it in the fields list in the Meta class. Remove RegDate from the fields list to resolve the error you currently have.

like Golfbauer said, you can't put RegDate in the fields list because none exists in your model, instead you can add the following and I think it will help you:
star_date = DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='gte',lable='date range')
end_date = DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='lte',lable='date range')

so you can filter by start date (or greater), start date and end date (range) or end date or less
